# WSO2 Token regeneration issue in store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 standalone on Linux machine, I have changed configuration for SSL to use own certificate. I followed this guide,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores

Now I am having some issue, when I am regenerating the tokens in store > applications > sandboxkeys or productionkeys then it is giving an error,

> Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 500

in logs,

```
[2017-09-20 06:58:56,114]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/revoke will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-09-20 06:58:56,114]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/revoke - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Wed Sep 20 06:59:26 UTC 2017
[2017-09-20 06:58:56,114]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing token 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101500, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender
[2017-09-20 06:58:56,115]  INFO - HandlerUtils Massage Info: Transaction id=5857679204959341105735016  Message direction=OUT  Server name=gitcapp.com  Timestamp=1505890736115  Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate
[2017-09-20 06:58:56,146] ERROR - subscription-add:jag java.lang.RuntimeException: Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 500
```

However rest is working fine, endpoints are working fine for HTTPS.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have configured `<APIKeyValidator>` section in `api-manager.xml` properly, like this.

```
<APIKeyValidator>
    <!-- Server URL of the API key manager -->
    <ServerURL>https://your.new hostname.com:9443/services/</ServerURL>
```

Comment: Updated the file, but the new line is replacing with the default value while restarting the wso2. Any comments/idea??

Comment: In APIM 3.x, the configuration model is different now. See https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/understanding-the-new-configuration-model/